# I have a physical Bitcoin, how can I exchange it for dollars

Tags: sell-bitcoins, physical-coins

I aquired a Bitcoin back in 2013,can I exchange it for dollars at a bank.

Comment: What do you mean physical bitcoin? do you mean casascius coin? you cant exchange that for dollars at a bank, you have to redeem the bitcoin first by downloading a bitcoin wallet importing the key and then selling the coins on exchanges or local peer 2 peer trading sites for dollars.

Comment: See answers to [Finding the Address of a Physical Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/76679/13866) for help in identifying your coin and whether it is worth anything and how to spend it.

Comment: If you have a physical Casascius coin, you will be much better off selling it for dollars on eBay or similar site, or perhaps at a coin (numismatic) shop. The value of Casascius coins usually exceeds the nominal bitcoin value. They are collector's items.

Answer (score 2):

There are a handful of people/companies who manufactured physical bitcoins, most notably [Casascius](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Casascius_physical_bitcoins).

If you have one of these, a little tamper proof seal should cover a private key. You can then import that private key into a wallet such as electrum, and send the bitcoin to an exchange where you can trade it for fiat, which will vary by your location.

If you do not have a bitcoin which contains a private key, then your physical bitcoin has no bitcoin value.

Comment: NOTE: if you do have a Casascius coin in good condition, then it is probably worth more if you do not unseal the private key. Casacius coins are considered collectibles, and if they are still sealed they can sell for much more than the face value of the coin. You may get more money selling the coin to someone, than you would unsealing it and transferring/selling the BTC on it.